# Проблема с element.checked

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с проблемой проверки на то выбран ли элемент type radio. Мне нужно сделать чтобы если элемент выбран то галочка убиралась. Дело в том что проверка проходит как-то странно и как только я нажимаю на элемент галочка тут же убирается. Похоже на то что сначало элемент становится выбранным, а уже потом идет проверка. Что в моей проверке может быть не так? Алертом выводит что один элемент выбран (на который я нажимаю), а другой не выбран, но в проверке я поставил checked true и по логике он не должен проходить. Спасибо

```
if((target == form.elements.male[0] && form.elements.male[0].checked == 
true) || (target == form.elements.male[1] && form.elements.male[1].checked 
== true)) {
    alert(form.elements.male[0].checked + ' ' + 
form.elements.male[1].checked);
    target.checked = false;
}
```

Comment: где ты выполняешь этот код?

Comment: @Grundy на минуту раньше написали ))))

Comment: в плане где выполняю? сначала у меня 
    document.onclick = function(e) {
    let target = e.target;
дальше я назначаю проверки какой же таргет ну и вот задаю такую проверку:
    if((target == form.elements.male[0] && form.elements.male[0].checked 
    == true) || (target == form.elements.male[1] && 
   form.elements.male[1].checked == true)) {
        alert(form.elements.male[0].checked + ' ' + 
   form.elements.male[1].checked);
        target.checked = false;
    }

Comment: _Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») **должны включать** желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и **минимальный код для** её **воспроизведения прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей_

Comment: ну я ж написал проблему. мне надо снимать галку с input type="radio", если она есть. её наличие я проверяю через checked (ture или false), но когда загружаю страницу галки нету, клацаю чтобы поставить её и такое чувство что она ставится и тут же убирается. проверку наличия галки написал в вопросе. + проходит аллерт в проверке, хотя галки то не стоит ни где на момент клика. такое чувство что сначала выполняется функция которая ставить галку, а потом выполняется функция по клику

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, сам ответил на свой вопрос когда свой же комментарий перечитал) оказывается функция которая ставить checked на элемент проходит по onmousedown(как только кнопка мыши опустилась), а onclick(когда кнопка мыши опустилась и поднялась), следовательно сначала ставится галка, а потом начинается проверка её наличия, по этому нам надо ставить такую проверку на onmousedown:

```
document.onmousedown = function(e) {
let target = e.target;
if(target == "Нужный нам элемент")
    target.checked = false;
}
}
```

либо явно на элемент применять:

```
element.onmousedown = function(){
if(element.checked) element.checked = false;
}
```